# how many seconds should you set your gopro time lapse if you want to do 7 days day and night that when played back takes only 12 seconds?

Tags: timelapse, gopro

I am a photography novice. I spent the last 6 years with nothing but a Canon Vixia HR700 I believe, but now I bought a used GoPro Hero 7 black and I want to learn how to do cool time lapses of my plants. I have some stuff that once germinated, takes 7 days for it to get to the cotyledon stage under some grow lights and I want to capture that in such a way that when played back, those 7 days/nights happen in 12 seconds of video.

Comment: At what frame rate do you want your 12 seconds of video to play? 24fps? 30? 60? Something else?

Comment: @MichaelC, I must admit that I do not know what my GoPro Hero 7 black is capable of in terms of frames per second and what the difference between 24/30/60 in terms of what the final video would look like. Would you be able to share the difference between each?

Comment: That's a question better asked on [Video Production](https://video.stackexchange.com/); timelapses have always been on the edge of on-topic here.

Comment: @PhilipKendall, thanks! Will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming 24 frames/second:

- Your final video: 12 seconds × 24 frames: 288 frames
- In 7 days: 7 × 24hours × 3600 seconds = 604800 seconds
- So delay between frames: 604800 ÷ 288 = 2100 seconds

Comment: You may want to check your maths for 12 * 24 :)

Comment: @PhilipKendall The math were good, but they were in octal :)

Comment: I must admit I didn't consider that possibility...